# how does compiler implement padding with pragma pack(1) and why should we not use?

Tags: c

I have written and executed following code in gcc compiler it does padding with structure. (even though it is not similar set of datatypes) its fine, But some people are recommended don't use pragma pack(1) why is that?.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#pragma pack(1)
struct a
{
        char a;
        int b;
        char c;
        int d;
};

printf("Size of struct :%d\n",sizeof(b));
***output***
     with pragma pack(1) = 10
     without pragama pack(1) = 16
```

Comment: Ask those people you mention. There's no absolutes, it all depends on context.

Answer (score 5):

One problem is that access to the misaligned members is slower — alignment is used to ensure speedy access.

People tend to use packing when they think they need to send the structure over the wire (a network connection) and don't want to spend time serializing and deserializing their data, not always realizing that there's a cost to avoiding that overhead that may be comparable to the cost of serialization/deserialization.  If the receiving CPU is big-endian while the sending end is little-endian, the work has to be done properly anyway by at least one of the computers.  The cost does vary with platform — RISC chips tend to be more stringent about misaligned access than CISC chips.  (On a DEC Alpha, for example, unaligned access resulted in a system call.)

Comment: Well, sometimes it can be very helpful to save some bandwidth by leaving out those useless bytes...

Comment: That's why serialization and deserialization are valuable.  There are many ways to do it; most of them do not involve packed structures.  The best methods are portable between machine architectures.

Comment: "access to the misaligned members is slower" - on some systems - 3 or 4 years ago when I benchmarked it on a newish (at the time) Intel it was actually the same.  There are other systems where you'll SIGBUS too - not just a system call simulating the read.

Comment: @TonyDelroy: Benchmarking can miss performance effects. Reading and writing unaligned data may run just as fast in some code as reading and writing aligned data. But it may be using more processor resources, so that other, more complicated code, that needs those resouces runs slower with unaligned data.

Answer (score 0):

`#pragma` non followed by `STDC` result in a implementation defined behaviour. `#pragma pack(x)` is commonly used by gcc or MSVC users on intel compatible architectures but leads to a non stricly conforming program.

It can make sense when portability is not an issue, but should always thinked twice: always prefere a strictly conformant way when possible.